# Can I use VSTS Release Manager to deploy a single web job under my app service without deploying the entire app service?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, ms-release-management

I have an Azure App Service which contains 5 web jobs. I have VSTS Release Manager set up to deploy the entire app service, which successfully updates my web jobs as well.

However, I want to deploy only a single web job without deploying the entire app service. I have the build set up successfully for the web job. But I am struggling with the configuration of the release pipeline. I've tried two methods:

**1. Copy Files**

[image]

Using this method, I am using `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/app_data/jobs/triggered/[my-web-job-name]` as the target folder. But when I go to find the files in the production environment (using Kudu console), they are not there. Since this completes "successfully", I think the target folder might be set up incorrectly. **What target can I specify to get the files in the production environment?** (as a side-note, do I need to do something special to have it deploy the contents of the drop.zip file?)

**2. Azure App Service Deploy**

[image]

This method seems to target the entire app service, and not a single web job. I have not tried running it using this method, as I am concerned it might wipe out my entire app service and replace it with my single web job. My thought is that there may be a way to set up a "sub-folder" of the app service to deploy into. But I'm not seeing any setting like that in any of the options. **Is there a way to set up the "Azure App Service Deploy" to deploy to a single web job folder?**

**Or, is there an entirely different way to deploy a single web job?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to make sure the structure of your artifact **matches the subfolders exactly**. See here: http://www.bravegeek.com/2016/12/03/Deploy-WebJobs-from-Team-Services/

**Relevant part:**
In your Build definition, add a Copy Files step after the build step.
Set these properties
Source Folder: src/WebJobTest/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/
Contents: **
Target Folder:   $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebJobTest\App_Data\jobs\continuous\WebJobTest

Comment: Thanks. That did it!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help 